# MPMoviePlayerViewController work fine with debug but crash in release on iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, mpmovieplayercontroller

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` works fine with debug but crash in release on `iOS9`

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerViewController];
```

My `url` is not nil.

it's working when `debug` in ios9 but crash when `release`, `xcode7` say:

> 2015-10-15 14:53:04.808 ********[5110:1680634] NSScanner: nil string
>   argument  2015-10-15 14:53:04.808 ********[5110:1680634] NSScanner:
>   nil string argument  libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly
>   threw an exception

Answer (score 1):

With iOS9, MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated, you should use AVPlayerController !

Comment: yes，but I must use MPMoviePlayerController  by some reason. and we can't just for iOS9

Comment: You can do like if iOS9 then AVPlayerController else MPMoviePlayerController.